# Windows service with SQL Loop throwing unhandled exception

Tags: c#, exception, service

I'm new to c# working with a windows service which has a timer but the autoreset is set to false so it supposed to run an infinite loop Querying to a Sql database.  If the SQL returns records the process runs fine, but when no records are found the service throws an exception after 10 - 12 minutes, System.StackOverflowException was unhandled which is not clear (to me). Not sure how to better capture the issue or how to correct. Any assistance would be apprecieated.

`private static bool LoadRequests()
        {

```
        // check for requests will return combined Header/Detail record
        bool RequestsLoaded = false;
        string XMLURL = "";
        string currentWorkingDirectory = "";
        string text = "";
        int rowcounter = 0;

        try
        {
            //Summary List will be a subset of requested items, by ID# 
            var SummaryInfoList = new List<SummaryInfo>();

            ReqHdrPlusDtlList myReqHdrPlusDetailList = new ReqHdrPlusDtlList();
            List<ReqHdrPlusDtl> myReqHdrPlusDetailList = myReqHdrPlusDetailList.GetReqHdrPlusDtlList();

            if (myReqHdrPlusDetailList != null && myReqHdrPlusDetailList.Count > 0)
            {
                // set check for last record 
                ReqHdrPlusDtl last = myReqHdrPlusDetailList.Last();

                // scroll through each record in  Request List 
                foreach (ReqHdrPlusDtl detailrec in myReqHdrPlusDetailList)
                {
        /// process id records ...
        /// ...

                } // exit for/each 

            }  
            else
            {
                //no records in list sleep for half a second before proceeding 
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                text = "Done sleeping...";
                WriteToAppLog(text);
            }

            //As soon as one request is fully processed, get the next pending record.
            LoadRequests();
        }   // ends try  
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteErrorMessageToAppLog(e);
            RequestsLoaded = false;
        }

        return RequestsLoaded;
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a recursive call which is causing the stack overflow problem.  Get rid of the recursive call to correct.  Possibly make a control loop as follows:

```
bool success = true;
while(success)
{
    try
    {
        LoadRequests();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        //Log Error ex.Message;
        success = false;
    }
}
```

Once you eliminate calling the function inside of itself, the stack overflow problem should be resolved.

***Edit***

One other comment, is the recursion is never-ending (no control statement to block execution) which is a big no-no.  If you have to use recursion then there must be a way to exit the method (a stop condition).  All that being said, almost every recursive problem can be solved iteratively and it can be very beneficial to do so, as it consumes significantly less system resources.  The above listed code would be an iterative solution.

Comment: Thank you.  The example is very helpful and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you look for [the exception in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx) it states the following.

> The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains too many nested method calls.

This exception often happens when you have an infinite loop, like in your code.
You are working with recursion (Recursion is an important programming technique that causes a function to call itself, [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z3dk2cc3(v=vs.100).aspx)). 
Because you keep calling your own function over and over again, you keep building up the stack, until it overflows.
You should rewrite the function so that it will actually end.
I suggest using a [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) to call your function every 500ms, instead of Thread.Sleep() because Thread.Sleep() also blocks any execution of code on that thread.

```
private DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;

private void SetUpTimer(){
    _dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    _dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    _dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
    _dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadRequests();
}
```

*Note: I didn't test the code, and I haven't written c# in a while, though it should help you get there*

Comment: Thank you. I will review Dispatcher Timer

Comment: @Fondah Let us know if our answers solved your question by upvoting and accepting an answer.